# Is it possible to read calendar events,reminders added by other third party applications from my application

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar, android-contentresolver

Is it possible to read calendar events,reminders etc., added by other third party applications    from my application using Content Provider Calendar events table?

I inserted a calendar from my application using following code,

```
getContentResolver().insert(asSyncAdapter(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI,"account@mydomain.com",CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL),contentValues);
```

Now my calendar is listed on [aCalendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.withouthat.acalendar&hl=en) Calendars List, But If I add an event in `aCalendar`,it is not added to my Calendar. Automatically It will add this event to CONTENTPROVIDER EVENTS TABLE with my calendar ID, or It must not be to write in EVENTS TABLE

I try to get events from my calendar using following code,

```
Cursor query = getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{CalendarContract.EventsEntity.EVENT_LOCATION}, CalendarContract.EventsEntity.CALENDAR_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(calendarID)}, null);
```

General Question : Why Calendar Applications are not provided list of calendars when adding a new event, to add this event to particular a calendar?